# SQL Server - Globally-scoped temporary procedure disappears immediately after closing query window in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am trying to get some data off a server which I only have read access on using an analytic stored procedure that has not been promoted there yet, so I am using it manually like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ###MyProcedure
```

Then in another query window I can run the new temporary procedure just fine. But soon as I close the query window which has the create statement, the temporary procedure is gone. To make matters worse, there are multiple subroutines that therefore require me to spam my workspace with open query windows to use this approach.

I thought globally-scoped temporary objects were retained until all referencing connections were closed. The only difference in my connection details (using F4 properties tab) between query windows in SSMS is the SPID, but I see the same connection name.

Comment: Why not just create a permanent procedure? I have a Utility database on most of my servers for things like tally tables and other "global" types of things. Would be a lot more stable than global temporary procedures.

Comment: @SeanLange I'm *guessing* the OP doesn't have any kind of DDL permissions on the database/Server. Being able to connect to SQL Server means you have access to create temporary objects though, no matter how little other permissions you have. It therefore seems they're using a global temporary SP as a work around until the update is propagated to their live environment. But, like I said, I'm *guessing*. :)

Comment: @Larnu that is a pretty solid deduction I had not thought of. Of course, if the OP doesn't have that ability and needs to use procedures perhaps they should speak to the DBA and get permission and avoid the insanity of temporary procs. :D

Comment: Yeah I only have read access to the server, but I need to use the upcoming code changes to compute some data today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known feature of using local and global stored procedures; that they only exist while the connection exists. Since each query window uses its own connection, the procedures are thus dropped when their defining query windows are closed.

Instead of using `CREATE PROC ##YourSP...` Try making it persistent in `tempdb`: `CREATE PROC tempdb.dbo.YourSP...`. it'll then persist until the SQL Server restarts (as tempdb is rebuilt every time the service is started).

*Edit: if you're using using SQL Server 2016+, you could also, instead, use `CREATE OR ALTER PROC`... This'll stop the `CREATE` generating an error if the service hasn't yet been restarted; and thus the SP hasn't yet been lost.*

Comment: But I remain connected to the server the whole time. I have numerous query windows connected to the same database, but as soon as I close the one I used to execute the CREATE ### statement the procedure disappears. Using the tempdb database is a good idea though, I'll try that.

Comment: @Elaskanator Each query window is it's own connection. That you have multiple connections doesn't matter; the one used to create the temporary SP was closed when you closed query window, and why the SP then stops existing.